# Bug in code where button does not always perform action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, swift3

I have a button in my application, and there are weird moments where sometimes when i click the button it does not always perform the code required. The app doesn't crash, but if I exit the app and open it again the button will continue to not work. The only way to fix the issue is to either turn off my phone or delete and redownload the app.

NOTE: This only happens once in a while, I am not sure why. Can the problem a possible constraint issue? This is the code for my button.

```
@IBAction func recordVideoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.movieFileOutput.isRecording {
        clipsCollectionView.reloadData()
        self.movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
        styleWhileNotRecording()
        turnFlashOff()
        stopTimer()
    } else {
        self.movieFileOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).videoOrientation = self.videoOrientation()
        self.movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = self.maxRecordedDuration()
        self.movieFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath:self.videoFileLocation()), recordingDelegate: self)
        styleWhileRecording()
        turnOnFlash()
        startTimer()
    }

    updateRecordButtonTitle()

}
```

> This is my updateRecordButton method. This is how i am aware of the
>   problem because the image doesn't always update.

```
func updateRecordButtonTitle() {
    recordButton.alpha = 0
    if !self.movieFileOutput.isRecording {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        let stop = UIImage(named: "stopButton.png")
        self.recordButton.setImage(stop, for: .normal)
        self.recordButton.alpha = 1
            })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        let start = UIImage(named: "recordImage.png")
        self.recordButton.setImage(start, for: .normal)
        self.recordButton.alpha = 1
         })
    }

}
```

> UPDATE!!

I just noticed that when this problem occurs, the timer does not stop either. So I am assuming that the problem is that it is not reading this correctly. Anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
if self.movieFileOutput.isRecording {
```

> UPDATE

I just realized another issue. I added print statements in my delegate capture methods.

```
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {
    print(42332)
}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    cropVideo(outputFileURL)
    print("Recording Finished")
}
```

When this issue occurs...All of these statements are printed. It prints

42322 and Recording Finished.

I realized what it does is that when this happens it records the video and stops it right away. I am not sure why this is happening????

Comment: Impossible to tell what's going on; please set up several breakpoints and tell us **which** branches do get executed (your if/else statements).

Comment: Set up breakpoints where the code doesn't seem to work? Okay i will try this, will this still be helpful even though the app doesn't crash when this happens?

Comment: You are trying to figure out WHAT is going on, but there is too little information. Which of `if self.movieFileOutput.isRecording { ... } else { ... }` is executed?  Is `updateRecordButtonTitle()` called at all? If so, which of `if !self.movieFileOutput.isRecording { ... } else { ... }` is executed? Perhaps the IBAction isn't being called to begin with?

Comment: I just updated the post. I added a print statement to the code and it always prints 1234 whenever the button is pressed. After testing the code, I realized that the application is not recognizing the 
if self.movieFileOutput.isRecording statement. It is not reading it in both functions.

Comment: Michael, your question is unreadable, you just copied slices of code, we don't have the big picture, try to add more code or anyway the necessary code to understand what we are talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 let cameraButton: UIButton = {
        let cameraButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        cameraButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        cameraButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cameraButton
    }()


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        addButtons()
}

func addButtons() {
        self.view.addSubview(cameraButton)
        cameraButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: self.view.frame.height*3/6).isActive = true
        cameraButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        cameraButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 190).isActive = true
        cameraButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 190).isActive = true
        cameraButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cameraTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
 func cameraTapped() {
        let videoPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        videoPickerController.delegate = self
        
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) == false {
           return
        }
        videoPickerController.allowsEditing = true
        videoPickerController.sourceType = .camera
        videoPickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        videoPickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(videoPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // After picking a video, we dismiss the picker view controller and present the editor view controller
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] as? URL
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        // We create a VideoEditorViewController to play video as well as for editing purpose
        let videoEditorViewController = VideoEditorViewController()
        videoEditorViewController.videoURL = videoURL
        videoEditorViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        self.present(videoEditorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```